Using forwarded headers with AKS Ingress
Problem
We recently migrated to Azure AKS with the application routing add-on using private DNS zones. However, we are encountering an issue where the real domain, e.g., auth.company.com, is not being forwarded from Azure Front Door to our AKS service. As shown in the example below, the forwarded headers from the service contain the private DNS address instead of the CNAME from the Front Door (auth.company.com).
"x-forwarded-for": "10.10.20.4",
"x-forwarded-host": "auth-dev.cluster.company.internal",
"x-forwarded-port": "8080",
"x-forwarded-proto": "http",
"x-forwarded-scheme": "http",

What are we missing? We've spent quite some time trying to figure this out, so any help is greatly appreciated.
Details
Our current infrastructure setup is as follows: Azure Front Door -> PLS -> Internal LB -> Ingress -> Service
Azure Front Door Origin configuration:


Welp,
For what you have chosen, documentation states:

Editing the ingress-nginx ConfigMap in the app-routing-system
namespace isn't supported.

And exactly what to change is the use-forwarded-headers configuration in this configmap.
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#use-forwarded-headers
Hopefully you can reassess your proxy infrastructure and see about substituting kubernetes ingress-nginx controller. You can always use an ExternalDNS controller hooked into your azure zones for that piece of the design.

Thanks for your reply! Do you see any options for using annotations on the ingress, such as ´nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet´? I haven’t been successful myself, but perhaps you have some insights ?

I'm not sure the azure application routing ingress suits your needs. It does not expose much ingress controller configuration.
